# Is getDefiniotionByName slow compared to the normal way?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, object

I've read somewhere that using getDefinitionByName() to dynamically get classes and then use those created objects is very slow compared to the normal way of using objects, however after some quick tests I made, I didn't find any performance difference.

I'm confused now, since I'm planning to make an app that will heavily rely on reading strings from a XML file and then instantiating objects from those classes dynamically found using getDefinitionByName.

The simple test I made consisted of iterating 200000 times in the constructor, doing some simple math process, both objects showed ~30ms of delay inside the for, using getTimer() to check.

The classes do not have the "Dynamic" clause though, they are regular classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getDefinitionByName is a different way to get to the same class.

Instantiating the class that way is not different to what instantiating the class directly would do. There's no inherent slowness to objects derived from a class you got via getDefinitionByName.

Answer (score 0):

No difference in performance for the created instances themselves. The global "getDefinitionByName" itself is slightly slower to use than directly instantiating with a class. This is easy to understand since a cast has to be performed.